# When Using Division ("/") in GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm having a problem on the division part, addition(+), subtraction(-), and multiplication(*) seems okay, but when I use the division(/), it produces wrong input... Why??

-Examaple - `10/2 = 0.2`<<---- why??

My code :

```
private void jButton12ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
                    SolveTEMP = Double.parseDouble(  jTextField1.getText() );
                    if ( addBool == true  )
                        SolveTEMP = SolveTEMP + TEMP;
                    else if ( subBool == true  )
                        SolveTEMP = SolveTEMP - TEMP;
                    else if ( mulBool == true  )
                        SolveTEMP = SolveTEMP * TEMP;
                    else if ( divBool == true  )
                        SolveTEMP = SolveTEMP / TEMP;

       jTextField1.setText(  Double.toString( SolveTEMP ) );
        addBool = false ;
        subBool = false ;
        mulBool = false ;
        divBool = false ;

    }
```

Comment: Can you show what TEMP holds?

Comment: Didn't you miss order? It looks that you do 2/10 = 0.2 instead of 10/ 2 = 5

Comment: It's suspicious that you've swapped `SolveTEMP` and `TEMP` , giving you 2/10 = 0.2; try setting a breakpoint or printing each variable

Comment: Check the values at the start of the method. DEBUG.

Comment: Learn how to use debugger.

Comment: Yes, `10 / 2 = 5`, but `2 / 10 = 0.2`.  Check that you are doing the calculation that you think you are.

Answer (score 2):

You have switched the numerator and denominator.

try

```
SolveTEMP = TEMP / SolveTEMP;
```

instead of

```
SolveTEMP = SolveTEMP / TEMP;
```

**Edit:**

For addition and multiplication the order doesn't matter.

Does subtraction work ok, or does it need to be switched as well?